# Warning: Illegal string offset - Syntax

Tags: php, html, ajax, database, pdo

I am creating a string with table context for it to be return to the ajax call and the table to be updated without page refresh. The table ids design for edit, remove, and insert capabilities as well.

I am currently getting an error on line 21 of mi code. (See comments in code). Apparenty my syntax is incorrect.

Can anyone point me in the correct direct? Thanks for your assistance in advance.

```
<?php  
include_once('database.php'); 
$output = '';  
$records = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC');
$records->execute();
$result = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$output .= '  
     <div class="table-responsive">  
          <table class="table table-bordered">  
               <tr>  
                    <th width="10%">Id</th>  
                    <th width="40%">Email</th>  
                    <th width="40%">Register Date</th>  
                    <th width="10%">Action</th>  
               </tr>';  
if($result === false){  
    $output .= '<tr>  
                <td colspan="4">Data not Found</td>  
           </tr>';  
}  else {  
    foreach( $result as $row ){
        $output .= "<tr><td>";
        $output .= $row['id']; /** @@@@ Error: Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in...**/
        $output .= '</td><td class="email" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>';
        $output .= $result["email"].'</td>  
                <td class="regdate" data-id2="'.$result["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$result["regdate"].'</td>  
                <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="'.$result["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">x</button></td>  
            </tr>  
        ';  
    }  
     $output .= '  
          <tr>  
               <td></td>  
               <td id="email" contenteditable></td>  
               <td id="regdate" contenteditable></td>  
               <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">+</button></td>  
          </tr>  
     ';  
}  
$output .= '</table>  
     </div>';  
echo $output;  
?>
```

Comment: You should var_dump the $row if theres no id in it theres your answer

Comment: Let me suggest you my [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo), it will help you to sort things out

Comment: Replace `fetch` with `fetchAll`.. that should do the job!

Comment: Thank you  Hatef. That worked vey well!!!!

Comment: Your Common Sense I will definitely read it. Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: JonathanRomer I will look into that thank you.